# MySql query ::group function is not defined in Model

Tags: database, product-collection, ce-1.9.2.4

I am trying to run this query :

```
    $collection = $this->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryId))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate))
        ), 'left')
    ->setPageSize($prodCount);
    $collection->group('e.entity_id');
    $collection->load();
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    return $collection;
```

As you can see there is nothing wrong with the query.

But I get this error when I run it:

```
  Array
  (
    [type] =&gt; 1
    [message] =&gt; Call to undefined method TypoStores_Filter_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::group()
    [file] =&gt; /var/www/vhosts/manglory.de/magento.manglory.de/app/code/community/Vsourz/Deals/Model/Deals.php
    [line] =&gt; 32
)
```

Typostores is an extension I use but the issue is that that extension is overriding only some functions and being extended from the core resource model.

I didnt get why group is not known by the resource model any more. It is a standart sql function in zend framework and also in magento.

So the Question is : How can I add GROUP function in that model and use it in general. Cause without it most of the queries will just throw duplicate item error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use**

```
->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

**Or use**

```
->groupByAttribute('entity_id);
```

Instead of **->group('e.entity_id')**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked ->groupByAttribute('entity_id);